# Python max length of j-th item across sublists of a list

Tags: python, text, formatting

I have a list such as:

```
x = [['aaa', 'bb','ccc'], ['ophkn','h','aa']]
```

**Assume that `len(x[i])` is the same for all valid values of `i` (0 and 1 in the above example).**

Now, I need to construct a list containing the maximum length of the jth item in each sublist of `x`.  That is, I need to know the following:

`max(len(x[i][j]))` over all values of `i` for a fixed value of `j`

So, in my example above, I would produce a list such as the following:

```
[5, 2, 3]
```

because

```
max(len('aaa'),len('ophkn')) --> 5
max(len('bb'),len('h'))      --> 2
max(len('ccc'),len('aa'))    --> 3
```

---

The reason I'm trying to find these max values is so I can print a table with filled space such as the following:

```
aaa    bb  ccc
ophkn  h   aa
```

So, if anyone has an elegant way of printing `x` such that it aligns in tubular format, please share!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `max()` over a generator expression.  For example, given `j` equal to 1:

```
>>> x = [['aaa', 'bb','ccc'], ['ophkn','h','aa']]
>>> j = 1
>>> max(len(i[j]) for i in x)
2
```

Or, looping over all values of `j`:

```
>>> for j in xrange(3):
...     print max(len(i[j]) for i in x)
...
5
2
3
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `zip()` is another way to do it:

```
>>> [max(len(a), len(b)) for a, b in zip(*x)]
[5, 2, 3]
```

As Robb pointed out in the comments, a generic and efficient way of doing this for arbitrary number of rows would be:

```
[max(len(b) for b in a) for a in zip(*x)]
```

Comment: I believe that OP is seeking solution for arbitrary number of rows.

Comment: I like this method the best but to generalize it to an arbitrary number of rows you could use a generator in the max: `[max(len(b) for b in a) for a in zip(*x)]`

Comment: Thanks @Robb. Updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use zip with a splat, eg:

```
x = [['aaa', 'bb','ccc'], ['ophkn','h','aa']]

maxlens = map(len, (max(el, key=len) for el in zip(*x)))
# [5, 2, 3]
```

Then use the appropriate `str.format` from the result.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you want all your output aligned based on the longest string in all your sublists:

```
x = [['aaa', 'bb','ccc'], ['ophkn','h','aa']]

max(len(s) for y in x for s in y) # find length of longest string

for x, y, z in x:
    print ("{0:<{1}} {2:<{3}} {4}".format(x, mx,y,mx ,z))
aaa   bb    ccc
ophkn h     aa
```

You can use [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) to align your text based on the longest length string.

Not tested too much but seems to work for arbitrary  length rows:

```
x = [['aaa', 'bb','ccc',"guido"], ['ophkn','h','aa',"van"],["foo","bar","foobar","rossum"]]

mx = max(len(s) for y in x for s in y)

d = {"m":mx} # to pass as key because you can only have only named arguments after *exp
for ele in x:
    print("".join("{:<{mx}} "*len(ele)).format(mx=d["m"],*tuple(ele)))

aaa    bb     ccc    guido  
ophkn  h      aa     van    
foo    bar    foobar rossum
```

We need to use a `dict` to pass  in the `max length/mx`, as we cannot have args  after `*tuple(ele)`, so we cannot use  index numbers like in the first example as  we would get only the first two substrings printed.

Using `{:<{mx}}` allows us to make the nested `{}` the align parameter.

`"".join("{:<{mx}} "*len(ele)` creates as many formatting `{}` as needed for the length of the row.

Comment: That's awesom! Is it generalizable to "rows" of any length?

Comment: will all rows be the same length?

Comment: Yes. All will be of same length.  It will form a big matrix of strings (none of the strings having spaces in them).

Comment: @synaptik, I added to my answer, see how it goes for you